# USB Sound Adapter

Tags: sound, adapter

I just bought a USB sound adapter 7.1 channel and it works well on windows but it doesn't work on Ubuntu as the sound is still getting out from the laptop speakers. How to solve this problem?
I have Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

the result of lsusb is

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching 
Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 
Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:021e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd 
(Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching 
Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please post the results of `lsusb`.

Comment: Done @MichaelBay

Comment: The device is **1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc.** and there are not a lot of info about it. It should work is what I think. Fully updating you system should be all you need. `linux-firmware` should be installed as well.

Comment: I updated the system but still not working @MichaelBay

Comment: If you google you'll find reports about it working in Raspbian https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40336/cannot-get-usb-audio-generalplus-technology-inc-to-work but this https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/problem-mit-extrener-soundkarte/ suggests it isn't yet supported in Ubuntu (read the last post with Google Translate, if needed).

Comment: Don't keep your hopes high but just in case check if something is offered at Additional Drivers?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pavucontrol` and `paprefs` to control the volume, and the output devices.

To install them use:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol paprefs
```

Then run it from the dashboard, or from terminal, and select the output device.

Comment: Doesn't appear in output Devices